# Prevent expansion of guide_colourbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

By default, `geom_raster` creates a gradient legend that extends slightly past the limits of the data.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(data=cbind(expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10), z=seq(0, 100, length=100)), 
       aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))

p1
```

[image]

Can I prevent the colorbar from extending beyond these limits (i.e., 0 and 100 in the example above)? Setting `limits=c(0, 100)` doesn't help, and setting `draw.ulim` and `draw.llim` to `FALSE` just hides the extreme ticks, but still plots the same ramp, e.g.:

```
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(
  limits=c(0, 100), guide=guide_colorbar(draw.ulim=FALSE, draw.llim=FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the colorbar is divided into 'bins' and the labels are placed in the middle of the bins. Because the default number of bins is [`20`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/guide-colorbar.r#L109), you will see the ticks in the middle of the bins at the ends of the colorbar, leaving space above the top-tick and below the bottom-tick. By setting the `nbin` parameter to a much higher value, you will use this behavior to your advantage because the height of each bin is now much lower and the height of the ticks resembles the height of the bins:

```
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), guide=guide_colorbar(nbin = 100))
```

which gives:

[image]

A close look at the legend will reveal that the ticks of the `0` and `100` values are now at the bottom / top of the colorbar.